# Using StreamBuilder to build widget from a Future in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

I am trying to build a widget with a list of values returned by an api call using StreamBuilder.  The stream is created from a Future using the fromFuture method.  I can see the api call being made and a value being placed into the Future variable but the creation of the stream never triggers the StreamBuilder.

Clearly I am missing something with my understanding of streams and how they work in Dart.  If anyone could clarify it would be greatly appreciated.

Stateless widget:

```
return StreamBuilder<List<Category>>(
  stream: api.getCategories(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if ( snapshot.hasData ) {
      final children = snapshot.data!.map((category) => Text(category.name)).toList();
      return ListView(children: children);
    }
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
);
```

API class:

```
  Stream<List<Category>> getCategories() {
    return Stream.fromFuture(this.apiCategories());
  }


  Future<List<Category>> apiCategories() async {
      // api call made here
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you've used `await` in your future and everything, you could first check if your connection is done or awaiting.

```dart
return StreamBuilder<List<Category>>(
  stream: api.getCategories(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if(snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done){
      if ( snapshot.hasData ) {
        final children = snapshot.data!.map((category) => Text(category.name)).toList();
        return ListView(children: children);
      }
      else{
        return Center(child: Text("No data returned from the API"));
      }
    }
    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
  },
);
```